# Canvas VS SVG for more than 600 Line Charts on a Single page

Tags: canvas, svg, d3.js

I would appreciate any help from the experts out there.

I am trying to create a single page with a table (25 by 25) 625 cells in total.
Each table cell should contain a simple line chart with 120 data points.

Each line chart should be able to zoom in/out and pan.

Performance is the key issue. What technology should I use? 625 Canvas or SVG elements?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: A single canvas should do fine...

Comment: Depending on the resolution each graph is and if you need to accommodate different devices then you might want to check out [Time series compression for adaptive chart generation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/CCECE.2013.6567840) for some ideas on compression. A copy of that paper is hosted by the [University of British Columbia](https://people.ok.ubc.ca/rlawrenc/research/Papers/functioncompress.pdf)

Comment: @Ken, problem is each cell in the table needs to be interactive they need to be selected. I do need to have separate multiple elements for each line charts.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks for the nice paper. For my case, #of data points will be fixed to 120 data points.

Comment: 120 data poinst in a 25x25 grid is 75,000 data items

Comment: @Ken, yes that is correct. I forgot to mention that 120 will be the maximum #of points per each line graph. We already have a backend producing optimized #of data points depending on dimension of each cell. I just want to know whether 600 Canvas is better than using 600 SVG elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to zoom and pan the charts of each table, canvas could have better performance. If you use SVG, you can use the [`d3.svg.axis`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) generator, if you use canvas, you may need to write your own. With SVG you can also modify the lines after they are created, or even customize them using CSS.Canvas is not always faster than SVG, it depends on the application and on the target platform. A quick proof of concept may help you to decide.